# Prevent UINavigationController's navigation bar to animate?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, xamarin.ios

My `UINavigationController`'s navigation bar is kind of static. This means, there is no back button, because going back in the stack is done via the first entry of the `UITableView` the controller holds. The title also always shows the name of the root item.
To achieve this I have added my own custom view to `UINavigationController.NavigationItem.titleView`

It looks a bit odd if a new controller is pushed in: the old navigation item vanishes, just to get replaced by one looking exactly the same.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior? I want the animation for the content of the controller, so pushing the new controller without animation is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your own `UINavigationBar` and implement your own delegate and custom animations for the content views.

It sounds like you'll only need one `UINavigationItem`, so that makes this model easy to manage.

Comment: So no automatic handling? Sad. :-) I'll postpone that change then and go on with implementing functionality.